# numpy argmax in array with multiple brackets

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, pytorch, torch

I have an issue in apply argmax to an array which has multiple brackets.
In real life I am getting this as a result of a pytorch tensor.
Here I can put an example:

```
a = np.array([[1.0, 1.1],[2.1,2.0]])
np.argmax(a,axis=1)

array([1, 0])
```

It is correct. But:

```
a = np.array([[[1.0, 1.1]],[[2.1,2.0]]])
np.argmax(a,axis=1)

array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0]])
```

It does not give me what I expect.
Consider that in reality I have this level of inner brackets:

```
a = np.array([[[[1.0, 1.1]]],[[[2.1,2.0]]]])
```

Comment: The first `a` is (2,2) shape.  The second is (2,1,2).  The third is (2,1,1,2).  `np.argmax(a, axis=-1))` will get the same values but with shape (2,), (2,1) and (2,1,1) respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.squeeze()` and a negative index.

```
a = np.array([[[[1.0, 1.1]]], [[[2.1, 2.0]]]])
np.argmax(a, axis = -1).squeeze()

array([1, 0], dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to increment axis value:

```
a = np.array([[[[1.0, 1.1]]],[[[2.1,2.0]]]])
np.argmax(a,axis=3)

array([[[1]],
       [[0]]])
```

But I still have inner brackets.

Comment: The inner brackets represent size 1 dimensions.  Do you know why you have a (2,1,1,2) shape in the first place?  Dimensions don't just get added at random!  You may need to brush up on the `np.reshape` function.